# What should I change 'RED' to?

Tags: c

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PARK 5
#define MAN  1

#if MAN
color = BLUE
#else
color = RED
#endif

void main(void)
 {
    #ifdef PARK
      printf("Hi PARK\n");
    #else
           printf("Hi Elice\n");
    #endif
    #ifndef MAX
          printf("MAX not defined\n");
    #endif
 }
```

'''

I'm studying about #if #ifdef.

[ color = BLUE ] is error. But [ color = RED ] isn't error.

I changed 'BLUE' to 'RED', but it still didn't work. Why?

Comment: You mean `MAX` or `MAN`?

Comment: Is `RED` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but let's try:

```
#define MAN  1

#if MAN
color = BLUE
#else
color = RED
#endif
```

`MAN` has a value of 1. In `#if MAN` the compiler evaluates if `MAN` is true. A value of 1 means true in C, so the compiler will compile the next line(s), `color = BLUE`. Note that this is not a complete statement because the `;` is missing at the end. Also, `color` should be a variable and `BLUE` must be defined (as a variable or as a `#define`).This may cause the error.

Because the `#if` part was performed, the `#else` part is not performed. Even though the same types of errors exist in that part, the compiler never "sees" it and so will not complain.

Does this explain your problem?

---

A correct version of the code could could be:

```
#define MAN  1

#define BLUE 1
#define RED  2

#if MAN
int color = BLUE;
#else
int color = RED;
#endif
```

This declares an integer `color` and initializes it.

---

**NOTE:** An important thing to realize in your study of `#if` etc, is that *it defines what the compiler will see for compilation.* So `color = RED` will never be seen by the *compiler*. `#if` etc or called *pre-processor directives* and it pre-processes the source code *before* handing it to the actual C compiler.

Comment: The time when the compiler does complain about the content of `#if ... #endif` (which is supposed to be skipped) is if it contains unbalanced features such as missing `"` or `#endif` or `*/`  etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane, you mean the pre-processor, as it needs to balance these tokens in order to identify the directives to process (a directive in e.g. a comment or string should not be processed).

Comment: Exactly, for example if there is a missing `#endif` from a nesting the pre-processor can't know *which* is missing (it ignores indentation which might be a clue for a reader).

Comment: @WeatherVane (in old days the directive should start at column 1 with no space between the # and directive name. Indentation was not allowed.)

Comment: First of all, I would like to apologize for the strange code by studying various things together. And what I'm curious about is that [color = RED] says nothing wrong, but [color = BLUE] says something wrong.

Comment: Of course, [BLUE] or [RED] did not declare otherwise. I asked a question because I had a strange problem doing it as an example from the university PPT. Thank you for kindly answering my awkward questions.